# Net::SSLeay post_https compilation error: Too many arguments

Tags: perl, openssl, perldoc

I'm interfacing with a payment gateway and not having any luck with Net::SSLeay and its post_https subroutine.  The payment gateway has issued me a client certificate that must be used for authentication.  The Net::SSLeay perldoc has the following example:

```
($page, $response, %reply_headers)
         = post_https('www.bacus.pt', 443, '/foo.cgi',           # 3b
              make_headers('Authorization' =>
                           'Basic ' . MIME::Base64::encode("$user:$pass",'')),
              make_form(OK   => '1', name => 'Sampo'),
              $mime_type6, $path_to_crt7, $path_to_key8);
```

My own version is below and returns the error **Too many arguments for Net::SSLeay::post_https**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSLeay qw(post_https);

my %post = (
    #snip
);

my ($page, $response, %reply_headers) = post_https(
    'www.example.com',
    443,
    '/submit',
    '',
    make_form(%post),
    'text/xml',
    '/path/to/cert',
    '/path/to/key',
);
```

Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of Net::SSLeay don't have the prototype that old versions have. Reading the source of old and new version I'd say the prototype was a bug (the code it calls can handle more variables than advertised).

The solution I recommend is upgrading to a newer version of Net::SSLeay. If that is not possible, calling it like &post_https can be a quick but ugly fix.

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version of Net::SSLeay did indeed fix the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is incorrect.  In my copy (Net::SSLeay 1.04) post_https is shown in the documentation with the example that you cite, but is declared to take a maximum of 6 arguments:

```
sub post_https ($$$;***) { do_httpx2(POST => 1, @_) }
```

I'm not yet sure how to make it work.

Edit: Try calling post_https the old fashioned way, as a subroutine using &post_https(...).

Answer (score -2):

You have an extra comma after '/path/to/key'

Comment: That’s perfectly acceptable in Perl and is considered good style.

Comment: Aristotle is correct.  The extra comma is there so that you can easily reorder list items as noted in Perl Best Practices:
http://www.amazon.com/Perl-Best-Practices-Damian-Conway/dp/0596001738